# Multiple API calls in python for Watson NLU

Tags: python, json, csv, ibm-watson, nlu

I am working on Watson NLU and I need to run analysis on questionnaire data. About 300 answers from separate people.
I am able to run it on "..." format text, but I'd love to get some help on how I can run it for all the 300 in one run. My current input is in excel with an ID column.
Thank you for looking into this.

```
nlu_api_key = "MY API KEY"
nlu_url = "https://api.eu-gb.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/MY INSTANCE"


import json
from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
from ibm_watson.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, EntitiesOptions, KeywordsOptions, CategoriesOptions,SentimentOptions
import pandas as pd


gtm_Q6 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\...\INPUT FILE.xlsx', sheet_name='OUPUT1')
print(gtm_Q6)


authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(nlu_api_key)
natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
    version='2020-08-01',
    authenticator=authenticator)

natural_language_understanding.set_service_url(nlu_url)

response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
    text='Where is the firetruck with the flaming paint the tigers on top?',
    features=Features(
        entities=EntitiesOptions(emotion=True, sentiment=True, limit=5),
        keywords=KeywordsOptions(emotion=True, sentiment=True,limit=5),
        categories=CategoriesOptions(limit=3),
        sentiment=SentimentOptions(targets=['investments']) #sentiment=SentimentOptions(targets=['stocks'])
        )).get_result()

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

| RESP_ID | ANSWER |
| --- | --- |
| Q6_109.000000 | team building |
| Q6_110.000000 | enablement and coordination between tech and sevices |
| Q6_111.000000 | skill building |
| Q6_113.000000 | speed to the right resources |
| Q6_114.000000 | information on the practicalities of the change at the moment |

Comment: so your question is really how to do something for each row of an excel file? `for row in gtm_Q6['<your_id_field_name>']: ...`

Comment: It kind of is, right. With the catch that I need to make calls to the API. + I need my excel rows to be formated in a way that the API can use it.

Comment: without knowing the contents of the excel/csv file it is really hard to help

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, I have added a short piece of the data as an example.

Comment: so the only thing that will change between the requests is the `<MY INSTANCE>` and it needs to be `RESP_ID`?

Comment: what is the type of response (`assistant.message().get_result()`). to which object i can cast it into?

Comment: Thank you a lot for looking into this, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution has been provided py T.J. Crowder in Python:
Here is the link to his original answer: [How to get rid of "\n" and " ' ' " in my json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221934/how-to-get-rid-of-n-and-in-my-json-file)

```html
json_arr = []
for text in gtm_Q6_df['ANSWER']:
    response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
        text=text,language = 'en',
            features=Features(
            entities=EntitiesOptions(sentiment=True,emotion=False,limit=3),
            categories=CategoriesOptions(limit=3),
            #sentiment=SentimentOptions(EntitiesOptions)
            )).get_result()
    
    #text = ("{ Answer: " + text + "}")
    json_arr.append(text)
    json_arr.append (response) # <==== change is here
    with open(r'C:\Users\...\Documents\Python NLP\WATSON NLU\OUTPUT JSON\data.json','w') as outline: #with open('data.json','w') as outline: ## data.json is the output file created ## the file can be renamed
        json.dump(json_arr,outline, indent = 2) # indent = 2 creates the pretty json!!
    
print("break")
print(json_arr)
```