# How to get rid of "\n" and " ' ' " in my json file

Tags: python, arrays, json

thanks for reading
I am creating a json file as a result of an API that I am using.
My issue is that the outcome gets has \h and '' in it and a .json file does not process the \n but keeps them, so the file becomes faulty.

This is my code, it is python:

```python
json_arr = []
for text in gtm_Q6_df['ANSWER']:
    response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
        text=text,language = 'en',
            features=Features(
            categories=CategoriesOptions(limit=3),
            )).get_result()
    #print("Input text: ",text)
    #print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
    
    json_data = (json.dumps(response, indent=2))
    json_arr.append (json_data)
    with open('data.json','w') as outline: #with open('data.json','w') as outline:
        json.dump(json_arr,outline)
    
print("break")
print(json_arr)
```

```js
['{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 113,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.734718,\n      "label": "/business and industrial/advertising and marketing/marketing"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.675452,\n      "label": "/business and industrial/business operations/management/business process"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.620496,\n    
  "label": "/business and industrial/advertising and marketing/brand management"\n    }\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 215,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.913644,\n      "label": "/technology and computing/operating systems"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.855434,\n      "label": "/technology and computing/hardware/computer"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.842841,\n      "label": "/technology and computing/hardware/computer components/chips and processors"\n    }\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 14,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.885687,\n      "label": "/automotive and vehicles/cars/hybrid"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.821966,\n     
 "label": "/automotive and vehicles/electric vehicles"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.77387,\n      "label": "/shopping/retail"\n    }\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 86,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.967686,\n      "label": "/education/homework and study tips"\n    }\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n  
  "text_characters": 80,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.822388,\n      "label": "/automotive and vehicles/cars/sedan"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.754857,\n      "label": "/automotive and vehicles/cars/hybrid"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.68194,\n      "label": "/automotive and vehicles/cars/car culture"\n    }\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 13,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.921873,\n      "label": "/real estate/architects"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.790383,\n      "label": "/business and industrial/construction"\n    }\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 52,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    
{\n      "score": 0.939684,\n      "label": "/technology and computing/computer reviews"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.931032,\n      "label": "/technology and computing/tech news"\n    }\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 14,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.979729,\n      "label": "/education/homework and study tips"\n    
},\n    {\n      "score": 0.850809,\n      "label": "/real estate/architects"\n    }\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 28,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.999484,\n      "label": "/education/teaching and classroom resources"\n    }\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 113,\n    "features": 
1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.734718,\n      "label": "/business and industrial/advertising and marketing/marketing"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.675452,\n      "label": "/business and industrial/business operations/management/business process"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.620496,\n      "label": "/business and industrial/advertising and marketing/brand management"\n    
}\n  ]\n}', '{\n  "usage": {\n    "text_units": 1,\n    "text_characters": 215,\n    "features": 1\n  },\n  "language": "en",\n  "categories": [\n    {\n      "score": 0.913644,\n      "label": "/technology and computing/operating systems"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.855434,\n      "label": "/technology and computing/hardware/computer"\n    },\n    {\n      "score": 0.842841,\n      "label": "/technology and computing/hardware/computer components/chips and processors"\n    }\n  ]\n}']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that you're creating multiple JSON strings (`json_data = (json.dumps(response, indent=2))`) and then adding them to an array (`json_arr.append(json_data)`), and then converting that array to JSON (`json.dump(json_arr,outline)`). So the result is a JSON array of **strings** (containing JSON).

You don't want to create a string before adding to the array, just include `response` in `json_arr`. Then it all gets converted together later by your existing `json.dump(json_arr,outline)` call:

```
json_arr = []
for text in gtm_Q6_df['ANSWER']:
    response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
        text=text,language = 'en',
            features=Features(
            categories=CategoriesOptions(limit=3),
            )).get_result()
    json_arr.append (response) # <==== change is here
    with open('data.json','w') as outline: #with open('data.json','w') as outline:
        json.dump(json_arr,outline)
    
print("break")
print(json_arr)
```

You may need to tweak that slightly, I don't do much Python, but the fundamental issue is that you're converting the data in each `reponse` to JSON **twice**. Do it just once, all together, at the end.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this solution is spot on.